# Can't prevent a binding error

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a datatable in my dataset that has these fields:

[image]

and I have a wpf window that the user inputs data into controls corresponding to these fields.  The controls are bound to a datarow as follows:

```
DataContext = myApp.Tables("VehicleExpenses").NewRow
```

When I load the form at run time I get this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467262
Message=Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Long' is not valid.
```

and this is the line that throws the error (this is generated code):

```
Return CType(Me(Me.tableVehicleExpenses.CategoryIDColumn),Long)
```

So the error is obvious but I have no idea how to prevent VB from pulling a Null value from the new row.  I've tried writing a blocking converter and setting UpdateSourceTrigger = Explicit but neither solves the problem.

Comment: Is it Nullable? Try `Return CType(Me(Me.tableVehicleExpenses.CategoryIDColumn),Long?)`

Comment: And you are sure that there is not null value in that column ?

Comment: @Verdoline That is generated code, not something that I wrote, so I am VERY reluctant to go messing around in there.  No, CategoryID is not nullable and it should not be.  That is a required field.

Comment: @searching.  In fact, I know there is a null in that column because when I add a blank row using the .NewRow method, the whole row is empty.

Comment: "I know there is a null in that column" but "No, CategoryID is not nullable and it should not be". This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Verdolino  It does make sense because it illustrates the problem I'm having.  By design, CategoryID is a required field.  But when I invoke the NewRow method shown in my OP, it puts a null in that field in the new row and THAT is the problem that led to my question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

--UPDATE 1--

Do not get confused by `Dataset` and this model. This middle layer is for user interaction and validation purpose. Saving data to db is in [2 stages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y2ad8t9c(v=VS.140).aspx). You will still need the auto generated properties and methods for `CRUD` operations.

Imagine this possibility (this is c#)

```
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public int VehId{get;set;}
        public Vehicle(){}
        public bool SaveToDb()
        {
            MyDataSet myDataSet = new MyDataSet();
            myDataSet.VehicleExpenses newVehRow = myDataSet.VehicleExpenses.NewVehicleExpensesRow();
            newVehRow.VehId = this.VehId;   
            myDataSet.VehicleExpenses.Rows.Add(newVehRow);
            // Save the new row to the database
            myDataSet.Update(this.myDataSet.VehicleExpenses);

        }
    }
```

---

Delete the row with that `Null` value in the `table` directly (if present). 
The `DataTable.NewRow` creates a new `DataRow` with  `column` defaults values (since nothing is passed). Not sure why it's not setting default value as 0 for the non-nullable column

Try this option instead of `myApp.Tables("VehicleExpenses").NewRow` if possible

```
'declare a VehicleExpenses in the form (you might have to create this class)
 Dim blankMo As VehicleExpenses

 ' in Form_load() set this object with new VehicleExpenses and against Datacontext
 blankMo  = New VehicleExpenses()
 DataContext = blankMo
```

You will need to add a separate save button and function to commit this model details to the database.

Let us know..

Comment: The field can only be `DBNull` if the column has the property `AllowNulls = true`. Otherwise it would be the default value of Long: 0.

Comment: Absolutely. I think rebuilding the dataset might be a good idea.

Comment: @Verdolino  I don't think that is correct.  One sets the default value of any field on the properties page.  The default value of all fields, no matter what the AllowNulls property is, is <DBNull>

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Verdolino  SQL Server 2016 and VS 2015

Comment: @Searching  I have been looking at your suggestion and it raises a more basic question for me: If I create a VehicleExpenses object, why even bother with the dataset and datatables.  I could use, as you suggest, the VehicleExpenses object as my binding source then, after verification, just load the data directly back into my database by writinbg a Save method.

Then I have even broader question.  Should I use the "object" approach for all my database interaction?  If so, of what value is the dataset/datatable approach?

Comment: @Searching  That "2 stages" link is really helpful.  I'm disappointed in all my noodling around MSDN I have never come across it.  I'll take some time to go through it all (I'm a relatively n00b) and combine that with your UPDATE 1 and then go from there.  Stand by .....

Comment: @SezMe How did this go ? Still having trouble ?